# difference between SendOrPostCallback and Action in multithreaded environment?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dependency-properties, begininvoke

I'm fairly new to working with threads. I was trying to set a `DependencyProperty`'s value:

```
    public States State
    {
        get { return (States)GetValue(StateProperty); }
        set
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                //(SendOrPostCallback)delegate { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }, //works
                (Action)(()=> SetValue(StateProperty, value)), //doesnt
                value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(States), typeof(FTPDownload), new UIPropertyMetadata(States.Idle));
```

I realized the hard way that in the setter you have to use SendOrPostCallback (as it provides an argument when calling the method). it does NOT work with Action (because of the missing argument.  And, wpf is really a bitch about it, debugging and finding the cause of the TargetParameterCountException with "no source available" and no clue at all.

Why do I have to use SendOrPostCallback there? and how should I know that in this case this is the right one?  Because actually calling the setter works via:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>State=States.Updating), null);
```

and using the SendOrPostCallback instead of course results in a TargetParameterCountException..

Just wondering if seemingly inconsistent thing like that are just common knowledge? Feeling a bit lost here, at least since googling around with SendOrPostCallback, Action and BeginInvoke as keywords had no meaningful results.

Comment: FYI, the setter for State is _not called_ if the update occurs as a result of the data binding system.  It will call SetValue directly.  As such, this approach to synchronization may not function as expected.  The general best practice is to make sure that all DP updates are occurring on the UI thread, which means isolating your UI logic (ViewModel) from any multi-threaded work going on in the underlying data and logic (Model).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant pieces of information:

1.The overload of [**`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591587.aspx) that you are using is:

```
public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority priority,
    Delegate method,
    Object arg
)
```

`method`:  A delegate to a method **that takes one argument**, which is pushed onto the Dispatcher event queue.

2.The [**`SendOrPostCallBack`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback.aspx) delegate is declared as:

```
public delegate void SendOrPostCallback(object state)
```

3.As for [**`Action`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx):

```
public delegate void Action()
```

Clearly, the `SendOrPostCallBack` delegate is compatible since it takes a single argument but `Action` is not, since it is parameterless.

Of course, you can use the [**`Action<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegate, which *does* take a single argument, if you prefer:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                        new Action<States>(arg => SetValue(StateProperty, arg)),
                        value);
```

Alternatively, you can use a [different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` that expects an argument that is of a delegate-type that takes *no* arguments, and get the C# compiler to do the dirty work for you in the closure:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                        new Action(() => SetValue(StateProperty, value));
```

Notice that `value` is a captured variable, so please be careful.

(Also, this answer doesn't deal with any thread-safety issues, only about the delegate signatures involved.)

Comment: hell, i'm stupid. of course the one method takes an argument while the other one does not. well, thanks. if only i didnt read putting thread-safety in dependency methods is a bad practice one minute ago.. ;) *sigh*